# ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::cin >>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream, std, cin

I'm trying to make something so you enter a file name and then text to write to the file but when I try to compile it it says this:

```
files.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
files.cc:11: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::cin >> filetoopen’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/istream:131: note: candidates are: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] <near match>
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/istream:135: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] <near match>
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/istream:142: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] <near match>
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/istream:250: note:                 std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] <near match>
files.cc:14: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::cout >> text’
files.cc:16: error: conversion from ‘std::fstream’ to non-scalar type ‘std::ofstream’ requested
files.cc: In function ‘char* openfile(std::fstream, char*)’:
files.cc:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open()’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:780: note: candidates are: void std::basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

char* openfile(ofstream file, char* words);

int main()
{
  fstream filetoopen;
  char* text;
  cout << "Enter the name of a file to write to." << endl;
  cin >> filetoopen;
  cout << "Now write somthing to the file." << endl;
  cin >> text;
  openfile(filetoopen, text);
}

char * openfile (fstream file, char* words)
{
  file.open();
  file << words << endl;
  file.close();

  return words;
}
```

I am very new to C++ an have no idea what any of this means. Also I'm not sure if how to make a function return an array so I kinda guessed. Can any one help?

Comment: Make sure you `#include <string>`, to get the operators that go with it.

Comment: What is the type of `filetoopen`? `text`?

Comment: Add it to the question (there's an edit button).  Also, you need to use `std::string`.  Extracting to an uninitialized `char*` is very bad.

Comment: I've already added the code supplied by OP in a comment to the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you wrote something like:

```
fstream filetoopen;
std::cin>>filetoopen;
```

to open the `fstream` on the file specified by the user. That's not the way it works: you have to read a string containing the file name and then open the file using the constructor of `fstream` or its `open` method:

```
std::string fileName;
std::getline(cin, fileName);
std::fstream fileStream(fileName.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fstream filetoopen;
cin >> filetoopen;
```

That is wrong, you cannot read from standard input a *stream*. You can read the *name* of the file to a string and then use that name to *open* the file stream.